# Override onTouchEvent in derived class

Tags: android

I have a view v2 that extends another view v1.
The parent view v1 has an onTouchEvent, but I would like the child view v2 to not use the onTouchEvent.

I set in the child view onTouchEvent to

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

                return false;



    }
```

Now when I create an instance of v2 in an Activity like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements V2.OnClickListener {

...

 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("TAG","BLA");
    }
}
```

The onclick event is not fired.
If I make V2 not extend V1 it is fired.
What am I doing wrong or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are just declining all touch events for this view. And the design in which child class doesn't want the parent's features is bad. Consider both `V1` and `V2` to inherit from `View` class or create base class for them.